# Pullbacks and pushouts with surjective functions and quotient sets?

Tags: category-theory, pullback

I'm in the category $Set$:

A pullback of two insertion maps $f,g$ with the same codomain is the *intersection* of the two domains.

A pushout of two insertion maps $f,g$ with the same domain (which must be an intersection of the two domains, which imply they are a subset to some other bigger set) is the *union* of the two codomains.

But I learned that when you create *dual notions*, you have to flip arrows, and turn monomorphisms to epimorphisms and vice versa.

So I wanted to take a look of the dual notion of an intersection:

$$
f: Z \to X \\
g: Z \to Y
$$

So if $Z$ stay's a normal set, and $f,g$ are surjections, than $X,Y$ are isomorphic to quotient sets. (I think?) pushouts are always a specific subset of the disjoint union. I almost think it is always just the disjoint union.

Is this correct?
Is my assumption that union is not really the dual of intersection correct?
What actually is the pushout (and pullback) of surjections?

EDIT:

Okay, so I'm making an educated guess at the dual of intersection in the category of groups.

So the coproduct in $Grp$ is the free product, and so the *construct* is a subgroup of the free product.

In my example I take the common domain for the product to be $C_6$, the cyclic group of order 6, and I take two normal subgroups of $C_6$, $N = \{0,3\}$, and $N' = \{0,2,4\}$
$$
f: C_6 \to \{\{0,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,5\}\} \\
g: C_6 \to \{\{0,2,4\},\{1,3,5\}\} 
$$

So the *free group with amalgamation* contains $\{\{0+N\},\{1+N\},\{2+N\},\{1+N'\},\{2+N'\},...?\}$

I'm afraid I'm not mathematically versed enough to solve this.

Comment: Union is the dual of intersection if you work entirely inside the category of monomorphisms into $X$, for fixed $X$. Then union is coproduct and intersection is product, in this category (which is a preorder).

Comment: Then is the dual in any category, as I tried to investigate, anything useful?

Comment: Sure. What do you want to know about it? Have you calculated it in examples? Groups will be a nice test case.

Comment: You have inverted domain and codomain in your second and third paragraph.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay, I made an attempt to construct such a pushout, please see my Edit

Answer (score 1):

In the category of sets, epimorphisms are surjective functions, and they indeed correspond to quotient maps. 
Namely, if $f:A\to B$ is surjective, take the equivalence relation $a\sim a'$ iff $f(a)=f(a')\ $ (called the *kernel* of $f$), then $f$ factors through a natural bijection $A/{}_\sim \to B$.

The pushout of general functions $f:Z\to X,\ g:Z\to Y$ is not a subset but a quotient of the disjoint union $X\sqcup Y$, namely it is 'glued' along $Z\ $ ($f(z)$ will be the same as $g(z)$ for all $z\in Z$).

Pushout of quotient maps correspond to *union* of equivalence relations, more precisely, the equivalence relation generated by their union. 
In your example of groups, we have to take the (normal subgroup generated by the) union of the given normal subgroups, which in your case gives back the whole group, $C_6$, so the quotient will be the *trivial group*. 
To get more convinced, pushout of a surjective homomorphism is surjective, and as both $C_3$ and $C_2$ are simple groups, we only have these surjections, up to isomorphism: $C_2\to C_2,\ C_2\to \{0\},\ C_3\to C_3,\ C_3\to \{0\}$.

Dually to the injective case, pullback of quotient maps correspond to intersection of the corresponding equivalence relations / normal subroups.

Comment: You talk about the *give normal subgroups*, which I assume to be $N, N'$, however $N \cup N' = C_5$ and not $C_6$

Comment: You have to take the *generated normals subgroup* of the union. $C_6$ doesn't have a subgroup with $4$ or $5$ elements. (Actually, $|N\cup N'|=4$.)